# Issues splitting a polygon layer by line

Tags: qgis, geometry, splitting

So we have a problem, and we can't a find solution.

```py
if feat_L.geometry().intersects(feat_P.geometry()):
    success, splits, topo = feat_P.geometry().splitGeometry(feat_L.geometry().asPolyline(), True)
    if success == 0:
        print(splits)
```

So first off feat_L is our line, feat_P is our polygon layer.
Our problem is that when we try to intersect the line with the polygon and using the `splitGeometry` function the result in the split is not the complete cut. It results in the second polygon not being complete.

The polygon before the split
[image]

And our result after:
[image]

What we want is to get also the remaining left polygon that after the split is not in our results. So the result is a polygon with 2 features when it supposed to have 3.